# Python Sqlite - Select Only Spans of Rows with Multiple Words

Tags: python, sqlite

I have a book in a Sqlite table that has one sentence per row. There are over 30k rows/sentences and the format of this table cannot be changed (it would break too many other things).

I also have several different spans of IDs that more or less divide the book into paragraphs. They are in tuples in a list, i.e. [(0,2), (3,6), (7,10) ...] or [(0,3), (4,9), (10,13) ...], etc.

I need to be able to return the spans that contain two words or more. That is, find say "water" and "earth" together within the same span/paragraph.

I looked at making views using each group of spans using GROUP_CONCANT to combine the sentences, but could find no way to do it since views cannot be appended.

Making 1000s of select calls like 'SELECT * IN book WHERE ID BETWEEN ? AND ? AND...' does not seem efficient.

Is there a way to return the spans that have hits with a single statement or maybe some way to use a temporary table to combine them?

Answer (score 1):

If they're sequential (or you can force ordering by ID to correlate with your spans), then you can use Python to do the grouping by just applying an arbitrary key to each group, and then using that as part of a groupby. eg:

```python
from itertools import repeat, izip, chain, groupby
from operator import itemgetter

testdata = [str(i) for i in range(10)]

spans = [(0,2), (3,6), (7,10)]    
groups = chain.from_iterable(repeat(idx, e - s + 1) for idx, (s, e) in enumerate(spans))

for k, g in groupby(izip(testdata, groups), itemgetter(1)):
    words = set(chain.from_iterable(el[0].split() for el in g))
    if words.issuperset(['3', '6']): 
        print words
```

You will need to modify this as to how it splits words and chooses what matches, but it remains one possible option.

If you're doing this often, you may wish to consider creating an extra table containing a single column representing the paragraph (instead of sentences), and apply a [full text index](http://www.sqlite.org/fts3.html) on that column which will make future queries a lot easier. You could utilise the above code to assist in building that table.

Comment: Thanks. Let me work with this a little and I'll get back. Concerning adding a new table with the paragraphs, I am wanting to avoid this because it will increase the DB size substantially per each paragraph table. With 5 added tables the DB would be 5 times larger.

Comment: @Tim with a FTI applied, it'd be a lot more than five times larger. That's the trade off you face though.